# MATLAB: creating looping plot with increasing integers

Tags: matlab

can you help me with one problem.
I'm trying to create a function that has sin() function but has to repeat (loop) with new values for N times of round:

e.g. sin(n*pi*x)*sin(m*pi*x) where x is the variable and n and m represent 1,2,3,4,5. 
n stands for row vectors and m for column vectors of a matrix, so the answer should be 
n x m matrix 
(in my problem the x=b ... b-a, which is a potential that changes (lowers) from 
b to b-a, so the energy potential is V(x)=0 from x=0 to x=b, V(x)=-E from x=b to x=b-a, again V(x)=0 from x=b-a to x=a,and outside x=0 and x=a the V=infinity). Hope this makes sense :)

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your function using a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html)

`fkt=@(n,m,x)(sin(n*pi*x)*sin(m*pi*x))`

Initializes the parameters, n contains row indices, m column indices. Adapt the size to your needs.
`[M,N]=meshgrid((1:5),(1:6))`

Now we can create a function:
`d=@(x)arrayfun(fkt,N,M,x)`

I hope rows and cols are not confused.